# (Git) Is it possible to have a folder in remote repo that is not in local repo?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have folder A, B and C in the remote repo. Since I am done with B and C, I only want folder A in my local repo to save my disk space. How to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Note: I am using Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert B and C to [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Thanks! I found an alternative though, because I was making a Github Pages. Still, good knowledge :D